# need help in Website fakehits generator problem with webrowser tool

Tags: c#

I found a a program on the net called alexa booster this program will generate fake hits to a certin website to increase traffic by accepting a URL and the a txt file with proxies and the program will start to generate fake hits a page views each time from a diffrent address(diffrent location) ... ANY WAY Im trying to make somethin similar

here is the picture of the program that I started to make

htp://www.sy-stu.com/stu/PublicFiles/ProgramsPhoto/prgrm.jpg

The original program that Im trying to duplicate accept a txt file that contain a proxy lists in the format of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy  Xs are ip Ys are port number
now :
 I couldn't open a text file and perform and use it in the streamreader thing.
 I couldn't set a time that after 5 second (set from the numeric counter) to refresh the page (with a new proxy address)

AND THE MOST IMPORTANT how i could not insert the proxy setting to the webrowser control and override the IE setting each time it refresh automatically.???

you can find the full code i did in the file

[**THE FILE**](http://www.sy-stu.com/stu/DownloadFiles.php?File=Ym9vc3Rlci56aXA=&Code=Mjg3&Kind=UHJn)

Comment: That's not going to work unless the proxies somehow have the alexa toolbar integrated into them, which is unlikely.

This is a waste of your time.

Comment: You need to be specific about your problem.  Just posting a project file and saying "write this for me" will not work here.  You need to show us the specific location in code you are having problems with.  We can't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: I dont want you to write any thing :) I don't know the way to open a file and use it in the stream reader this is one point the second how can I change the proxy within a time (by the numeric counter) and reloaed the page automaticaly without pressing the button again and again ...Ihope you got it MR hogan

Comment: You're asking at least three separate questions here, and both of your links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# , just make a simple httpwebrequest based crawler sort of application, make it proxified and run it with multiple threads.